# How to Remove or Hide Filter Operators Dropdown List

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

The `filterMenuInit` event isn't firing on my grid. I want the **AccountNumber** field to have a filter, however I want to completely remove or hide the dropdown where it says "Is Equal To", "Does Not Contain", etc. The code to remove the dropdown is in the `filterMenuInit` configuration but the function isn't firing when the grid loads. Here is my code:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "/api/client"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ClientID: { type: "number" },
                                Name: { type: "string" },
                                Branch: { type: "string" },
                                Department: { type: "string" },
                                AccountNumber: { type: "number" }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    pageSize: 20,
                    serverPaging: false,
                    serverFiltering: false,
                    serverSorting: true
                },
                height: 500,
                scrollable: true,
                filterable: {
                    mode: "row",
                    extra: "false"
                },
                filterMenuInit: function(e) {
                    if (e.field === "AccountNumber") {
                    var firstValueDropDown = e.container.find("select:eq(0)").data("kendoDropDownList");

                        setTimeout(function () {
                            firstValueDropDown.wrapper.hide();
                        })
                    }
                },
                sortable: false,
                pageable: true,
                columns: [{
                    field: "AccountNumber",
                    width: "150px",
                    title: "Account #"
                }, {
                    field: "Branch",
                    filterable: false,
                    width: "100px",
                    title: "Branch"
                }, {
                    field: "Department",
                    filterable: false,
                    width: "100px",
                    title: "Department"
                }, {
                    field: "Name",
                    template: '<a href="/client/#=ClientID#">#=Name#</a>',
                    title: "Client Name"
                }, {
                    filterable: "false",
                    template: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span><a href="/client/#=ClientID#/invoice">View Invoices</a>',
                    width: "150px"
                }, {
                    filterable: "false",
                    template: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> <a href="/client/#=ClientID#/workorder">View Work Orders</a>',
                    width: "150px"
                }
            ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Entered debug mode in the browser and the event never fires so the dropdown remains active.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code at you column definition

```
filterable: {
    cell: {
        showOperators: false
    }
}
```

or you can define in schema that it is number, it will solve it as well

Here is [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UhIQo/2)